# Landsat Gap Fill

Tags: landsat, envi

I am looking for a Landsat gap fill method for quantitative data analysis. The best I have found is a reference to a method called "single file gap fill triangulation" using in ENVI, but am unsure how this method was carried out and I couldn't find a tool in ENVI.

I don't normally use ENVI, is there method or documentation for preforming this gap fill in ENVI v5.0? Or another method out there?

Comment: I've updated the link to [single date Triangulation interpolation](http://www.exelisvis.com/Learn/CodeDetail/TabId/220/ArtMID/904/ArticleID/9800/1311.aspx) in [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30316/2856)

Answer (score 1):

The open-source GIS Whitebox GAT (http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/) has a tool called 'Fill Missing Data Holes'. It performs well for smaller holes, although I suspect that any technique will not be as effective for large data gaps.
[image]

[image]

[image]